# JMeter distributed testing from Java code - csv dependent data in slaves

Tags: java, csv, jmeter, slave, distributed-testing

I am running JMETER DISTRIBUTED test from my JAVA CODE. So far , it is working fine for the JMX files that doesn't have any dependent CSV test data. Now , I'd like to run a test with csv dependent data but it seems the csv file needs to be placed in the SLAVE machines as well. Is there a way we could execute the test without placing the dependent CSV file in SLAVE machines. I am trying to automate the tests through java code , so it would not be feasible for me to manually place the csv files in SLAVE machines. Please let me know your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2):

As of current [JMeter version 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) there is no support of transferring dependent files to the slave machines, only the .jmx script is being passed from master over the network.

You could consider using a plugin like [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) or [Redis Dataset](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/Using-Redis-Dataset-JMeter-Plugin) or put your test data into the database and use [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) for fetching the data from the centralized remote storage instead of depending on local CSV files.

Alternatively you can use [jCIFS](https://www.jcifs.org/) or [jSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) libraries to copy the .CSV files to the slaves from your JAVA CODE

Comment: Hi @Dmitri , Thank you so much for the suggestion. Appreciate your help on this, it really makes sense. Any idea if JMETER would support this feature in the upcoming releases?